# How can I preg_match a character-run of individual characters?

Tags: php, regex, character

Using

```
(a{4,})
```

I can match 4 or more of a specific characters in a row

> a aaa **aaaaaa** aa

and with

```
([0-9]{4,})
```

I can match 4 or more of a specific group of characters in a row

> 1 123 **1234321** 12

But I'm looking for a way to catch runs of an individual character in a string of characters. Meaning: I have a collection of strings in the range `[a-zA-z0-9]`. Whenever one of these characters is repeated more than 4 times, the regex should match up.

To give you a more practical example: in...

> This is Teeeeeeest version 1.0.33333.4

...it should be able to match the run of the `e` character and the run of the `3` character.

Now, the following clearly doesn't satisfy my needs...

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,})
```

...since it would simply catch all runs of the allowed chars. But I only need to catch the moments where a single character is repeated 4 or more times.

I really want to avoid looping all 64 possible characters through individual regexes with a `for(...)` and I'm sure there *"must be a way"* to do it with one regex. But since I've tried near to everything and I'mm close to hitting my head against the wall, I opted-in to hope that someone can help me with this by pushing me in the right direction.

How can I `preg_match` a character-run of individual characters? (aka: What would the regex look like?)

**EDIT (after accepting answer)**

Thanks for your answer(s) and comment(s),because the only option I found to do what I wanted was

> (a{4,}|b{4,}|c{4,}|d{4,}|e{4,}|f{4,}|g{4,}|h{4,}|i{4,}|j{4,}|k{4,}|l{4,}|m{4,}|n{4,}|o{4,}|p{4,}|q{4,}|r{4,}|s{4,}|t{4,}|u{4,}|v{4,}|w{4,}|x{4,}|y{4,}|z{4,}|A{4,}|B{4,}|C{4,}|D{4,}|E{4,}|F{4,}|G{4,}|H{4,}|I{4,}|J{4,}|K{4,}|L{4,}|M{4,}|N{4,}|O{4,}|P{4,}|Q{4,}|R{4,}|S{4,}|T{4,}|U{4,}|V{4,}|W{4,}|X{4,}|Y{4,}|Z{4,}|0{4,}|1{4,}|2{4,}|3{4,}|4{4,}|5{4,}|6{4,}|7{4,}|8{4,}|9{4,})

but that just didn't feel good... and it sure doesn't look *healthy* either, does it? ;)

Anyway, I ended up with this...

```
preg_match_all('#([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{3}#',
               'This is Teeeeeeest version 1.0.33333.4',
               $matches));
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: I think this is a job for backreferences: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the regex "backreference" capability. In your case it would be:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{3}
```

See this [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/v0c3a) using your test string.

Comment: Thanks for setting up that fiddle! [+1] Btw: that seems to be a pretty usable site. *bookmarked*

Comment: Glad it was helpful, although I confess that I couldn't figure out a way to get the php variant to match multiple occurrences of the regex within a string.

Comment: `preg_match_all` handles that one. ;)